# VSTS - authentication error SSH

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm using SSH to authenticate in VSTS to manager my projets and repositories.
Since last monday(07/09), this process stoped to work. I'm receiving the error bellow:

> Details: The method or operation is not implemented. fatal: Could not
>   read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

The result of ssh -v:

```js
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/node/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/node/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for vs-ssh.visualstudio.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to vs-ssh.visualstudio.com [191.232.37.247] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/node/.ssh/paulo.simao@aperam.visualstudio.com.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/node/.ssh/paulo.simao@aperam.visualstudio.com.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SSHBlackbox.10
debug1: no match: SSHBlackbox.10
debug1: Authenticating to vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:22 as 'aperam'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:ohD8VZEXGWo6Ez8GSEJQ9WpafgLFsOfLOtGGQCQo6Og
debug1: Host 'vs-ssh.visualstudio.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/node/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/node/.ssh/paulo.simao@aperam.visualstudio.com.pem
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to vs-ssh.visualstudio.com ([191.232.37.247]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
shell request failed on channel 0
```

Does anybody has idea what its occorring?

Comment: Provide output of `ssh -v` with the username and address of the VSTS server from Git Bash.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand what I need to do...

Comment: Open Git Bash and navigate to the folder with repository. Run `git remote -v` to get the remote address such as `git@host.com:folder/repo.git`. From the Git Bash try to execute `ssh -v git@host.com` (replace with the information you got with previous command) and append the information to your question.

Comment: In general, it is likely to be caused by a change in the SSH keys, but we actually need to be certain of the cause to help you.

Comment: @petrpulc, done!

Comment: Ok, so the key does not seem to be a problem, still with Git Bash in the folder with repository try e.g. `git pull`.

Comment: @petrpulc, when i try this command, i get the same error described above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174806/discussion-between-petrpulc-and-carlos-henrique-biazin-esteves).

Comment: @CarlosHenriqueBiazinEsteves Can you show the screen shot for the output show from `git remote -v` command and the url shows in VSTS web page? Besides,   can you clone the VSTS git repo successful now?